# Magento 2.3 - removing the login/Signin button on checkout page

Tags: magento2, php, css

I use magento 2.3.2 and i cant locate the SIGN IN button in the checkout page of my website..

i have tried to access 
magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\onepage\link.phtml
 and many others but still cant find the location and the code that is enabling it..
i need it removed.
see image of the button i want removed..
[image: checkout issue]

Answer (score 3):

**1. Create XML Layout file checkout_index_index.xml in your theme path like below**

your-theme/Magento_checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

**2.Add Below Code in file checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="authentication" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

This disables the JS component that renders the authentication element.
Hope this help you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove it from header from checkout page use CSS

```
.checkout-index-index .authentication-wrapper{
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. where do i place it?

Comment: In css file of your theme